# How does cPanel's addon domain work?

Tags: apache, cpanel, virtualhost

So, I am new to the world of cPanel. How does cPanel's addon domain feature work? Does it utilise Apache Web server's VirtualHost feature? Or does it do something else?

Answer (score -1):

It simply creates a directory for each add on domain and directs traffic to it.  If you have an existing domain example.com and you want to add example-1.com, it creates another directory example-1.com at your root.  It then creates multiple paths to your domain,  http(s)://example-1.com and http(s)://example-1.com/example.com.  If you're using a CMS like WordPress, you can then install WordPress directly in the new directory.

See image below:

[image]

Comment: "...and directs traffic to it" - but "how" - that would seem to be what the OP is asking, rather than simply what it does. (_Aside:_ You wouldn't expect `http(s)://example-1.com/example.com` to be accessible, perhaps `http(s)://example.com/example-1.com`, if `example-1.com` is created as a subdirectory off the main domains document root - but that isn't necessarily the case - in fact, that is often best avoided by using a directory outside the main domain's document root.)

Comment: @MrWhite indeed I'm interested in the technology

Comment: @MrWhite it actually does do a `http(s)://example-1.com/example.com` (I have 3 add on domains in my system).  I should clarify, that it's not a directory within the website (i.e., it's not visible like a virtual directory)., but a directory within the user's parent file system directory.

Comment: @Trebor it's a directory within public_html right? And how does tee server know which Web page to serve for a request? Does it utilise Apache Web server:a VirtualHost function? Or does it do something else?

Comment: @lpydawa, doesn't have to be, unless you want it to be.  Domains can be at the same directory level as public_html (not inside).  During domain creation, you can specify the document root.  See `https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/domain-names/adding-addon-domains-in-cpanel/`